# OkHttpClient enqueue , как заставить код ожидать ответа?

Tags: java, android-studio, mobile-development

Как заставить программу ожидать выполнение call_summoner_id?

```
 public void get_summoner_id(String REGION, final String summoner_name) {
    final Request request = new Request.Builder().url(this.GETURL.get_url_summoner_by_summoner_name(summoner_name, REGION)).build();
    GETCALL.call_summoner_id(request);
    set_summoner_id(GETCALL.summoner_id);
}

   public void call_summoner_id(Request request){
    client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            listener.onFailure();
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
            try {
                Response response_summoner = response;
                System.out.print(response_summoner);
                JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response.body().string());
                final String new_summoner_id = json.getString("id");
                summoner_id = new_summoner_id;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Этого можно добиться синхронным запросом: https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Recipes#synchronous-get

Answer (score 0):

В лоб:

```
int beforeRequest = GETCALL.summoner_id;
GETCALL.call_summoner_id(request);
int afterRequest = GETCALL.summoner_id;

while(beforeRequest == afterRequest){
    //Thread.sleep(500);
    afterRequest = GETCALL.summoner_id;
}

set_summoner_id(GETCALL.summoner_id);
```

Вы мало информации выложили, но из того что есть, возможно вам стоит создать наблюдателя, который при изменении `GETCALL.summoner_id` будет выполнять нужную вам работу.

[Наблюдатель (шаблон проектирования)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)#Java)

Answer (score 0):

Это возможно только если выполнять все действия в одном потоке. В случае андроида это должен быть не основной поток. У вас, видимо, нужно некий `ID` присвоить в главном потоке, при этом `ID` получить из результата сетевого запроса. В этом случае вы не можете сделать это в одном потоке, т.к. запросы в сеть из основного потока прямо запрещены.

Вам надо полностью менять логику. Исходить надо из того, что сетевой запрос может длиться неизвестное время (иногда несколько минут) и часто просто завершается ошибкой. Т.е. вам надо запускать запрос и забывать о нём. Далее, в колбэках его завершения обрабатывать успешное/неуспешное завершение.

Простой синхронный подход в случае работы с данными из к-л источников (сеть/БД) не получится нормальным никак.